# My InputAccessoryView didn't disappear on Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

I make toolbar to make done, or next button for Numberpad Type keyboard

But on simulator if i touch textfield, keyboard did't show and only inputAccessoryView show.

And `cmd` + `k` keyboard show, but if i tapped `cmd` + `k` again
only keyboard disappear and toolbar didn't disappear

[image]

What is the problem with my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var phoneTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var identifierTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addButtonToTextField(textField: phoneTextField)
        addButtonToTextField(textField: identifierTextField)
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    func addButtonToTextField(textField: UITextField){
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        if textField == phoneTextField {
            let nextBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneBtnPressed))
            toolBar.items = [flexibleSpace, nextBtn]
        }else if textField == identifierTextField {
            let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneBtnPressed))
            toolBar.items = [flexibleSpace, doneBtn]
        }

        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    @objc func doneBtnPressed(){
        if phoneTextField.isFirstResponder{
            identifierTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }else if identifierTextField.isFirstResponder{
            identifierTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything should be OK if you test it in an actual iOS device. What you are describing is the default behavior of the simulator.

Hope it helps.